# onchange didn't work inside my function that render json parse

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this code from w3school and modified it to suit my need and I come up with this code

```
<div id="city"></div>
          <p id="demo"></p>
          <div id="province"></div>
          <script>
          (function () {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://getpark.net/city/read";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            function myFunction(response) {
                var arr = JSON.parse(response);
                var i;
                var out = "<div class='row'>" + 
                            "<div class='large-12 columns'>" +
                            "<label>City</label>" +
                             "<select id='select' name='city' onchange='change()'>";

                for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    out += "<option value='" +
                    arr[i].cityId +
                    "'>" +
                    arr[i].cityName +
                    "</option>";
                }
                out += "</select>" +
                      "</div>" +
                     "</div>";
                document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = out;
            }

            function change() {
              var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
            }

          })();
```

but why that onchange in change() function didn't work out? I see it from w3school.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change-function should be in the global scope. You only have to move the declaration of the function directly after the script-tag.

```
<script>
function change() {
  var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
(function () {
[..]
```

Comment: this exactly right.. I already try this a couple minutes ago and your answer is the same with my solution thank you.. @Michael Walter